# Replace all the occurrences of specific words

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Suppose that I have the following sentence:

```
bean likes to sell his beans
```

and I want to replace all occurrences of specific words with other words. For example, `bean` to `robert` and `beans` to `cars`.

I can't just use `str.replace` because in this case it'll change the `beans` to `roberts`.

```
>>> "bean likes to sell his beans".replace("bean","robert")
'robert likes to sell his roberts'
```

I need to change the whole words only, not the occurrences of the word in the other word. I think that I can achieve this by using regular expressions but don't know how to do it right.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you use regex, you can specify word boundaries with `\b`:

```
import re

sentence = 'bean likes to sell his beans'

sentence = re.sub(r'\bbean\b', 'robert', sentence)
# 'robert likes to sell his beans'
```

Here 'beans' is not changed (to 'roberts') because the 's' on the end is not a boundary between words: `\b` matches the empty string, but *only* at the beginning or end of a word.

The second replacement for completeness:

```
sentence = re.sub(r'\bbeans\b', 'cars', sentence)
# 'robert likes to sell his cars'
```

Comment: I suppose the parentheses aren't necessary, they just made the regex more readable (at least to me).

Comment: For some reason this does not seem to get all occurrence of U.S.

Answer (score 4):

If you replace each word one at a time, you might replace words several times (and not get what you want). To avoid this, you can use a function or lambda:

```
d = {'bean':'robert', 'beans':'cars'}
str_in = 'bean likes to sell his beans'
str_out = re.sub(r'\b(\w+)\b', lambda m:d.get(m.group(1), m.group(1)), str_in)
```

That way, once `bean` is replaced by `robert`, it won't be modified again (even if `robert` is also in your input list of words).

As suggested by **georg**, I edited this answer with `dict.get(key, default_value)`. 
Alternative solution (also suggested by **georg**):

```
str_out = re.sub(r'\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(d.keys()), lambda m:d.get(m.group(1), m.group(1)), str_in)
```

Comment: You should be able to make that simpler (and faster) and remove the `if` to directly look in the dict if you use `\bbeans?\b` for regex and use `m.group(0)` (for the whole match) in the lambda.

Comment: I would like this to be general enough, so 1 regex can cope with any input text + any list of words to replace. So I don't want `beans` in my regex.

Comment: I see. It's just that it will check each and every word and I believe that's the main bottleneck.

Comment: I agree it should be faster to hard-code 1 regex per word to replace. But there is still the problem of making sure that once replaced, a word is not replaced again by another regex.

Comment: No, that problem is no more a problem. `\bbeans?\b` matches both `bean` and `beans` so that what you get in the lambda is `d['bean']` and `d['beans']` and the two are thus treated differently.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. I just assumed OP meant `bean` and `beans` as an example. If those are the only 2 words to modify, then yes, I agree, your regex would be faster.

Comment: You can simplify the lambda like this: `lambda m: d.get(m.group(1), m.group(1))`

Comment: Another possible optimization is to create a regex dynamically from the dict: `regex = r'\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(d)` so that doesn't have to check all words.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was a better way to write it, but could not remember dict.get() :).

Comment: Regarding the regex with all keys joined, it could be faster. That said, checking whether a word is in a dict is fast too (it's in O(1) with the hashing system), whereas a regex with `(word1|word2|...|wordn)` is in O(n). So if the list becomes very large, it might be faster with a dict. So unless we have timings, or know the size of the list + number of words in the text, I think it could go either way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dirty way to do this. using folds

```
reduce(lambda x,y : re.sub('\\b('+y[0]+')\\b',y[1],x) ,[("bean","robert"),("beans","cars")],"bean likes to sell his beans")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
"bean likes to sell his beans".replace("beans", "cars").replace("bean", "robert")
```

Will replace all instances of "beans" with "cars" and "bean" with "robert". This works because `.replace()` returns a modified instance of original string. As such, you can think of it in stages. It essentially works this way:

```
 >>> first_string = "bean likes to sell his beans"
 >>> second_string = first_string.replace("beans", "cars")
 >>> third_string = second_string.replace("bean", "robert")
 >>> print(first_string, second_string, third_string)

 ('bean likes to sell his beans', 'bean likes to sell his cars', 
  'robert likes to sell his cars')
```

Comment: I can't do it this way in real task, because the order of this replacements is undefined