# Removing numbers mixed with letters from string

Tags: python, regex, string

Suppose I have a string such as :

```
string = 'This string 22 is not yet perfect1234 and 123pretty but it can be.'
```

I want to remove any numbers **which are mixed with words**, such as `'perfect1234'` and `'123pretty'`, **but not** `'22'`, from my string and get an output as follows:

```
string = 'This string 22 is not yet perfect and pretty but it can be.'
```

Is there any way to do this in Python using regex or any other method? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851791/removing-numbers-from-string

Comment: Seems like OP wants to eliminate only digits that are part of words, not any digits in the string. (Word boundary matters)

Comment: However, it is not a well-asked question. @PJay, any patterns you tried? What issues do you have with your code? Also, check [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of specific words in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631695/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-specific-words-in-python)

Comment: I want to remove any digits that get mixed up with letters or any other non alphanumeric character such as '700/-'. In fact I also wanted to remove all numbers from my string such as phone numbers of the format '+91 ....'. Could you help me with this format as well? Any kind of digits appearing in my string need to be removed.

Answer (score 5):

```
s = 'This string 22 is not yet perfect1234 and 123pretty but it can be.'

new_s = ""
for word in s.split(' '):
    if any(char.isdigit() for char in word) and any(c.isalpha() for c in word):
        new_s += ''.join([i for i in word if not i.isdigit()])
    else:
        new_s += word
    new_s += ' '
```

And as a result:

```
'This string 22 is not yet perfect and pretty but it can be.'
```

Comment: More complicated than a regex (IMO), but probably faster in Python. Good answer, and I think more targeted to the OP's original intent.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to preserve digits that are by themselves (not part of a word with alpha characters in it), this regex will do the job (but there probably is a way to make it simpler):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"\d*([^\d\W]+)\d*")
s = "This string is not yet perfect1234 and 123pretty but it can be. 45 is just a number."
pattern.sub(r"\1", s)
'This string is not yet perfect and pretty but it can be. 45 is just a number.'
```

Here, 45 is left because it is not part of a word.

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
re.sub(r'\d+', '', string)
```

Comment: should use raw string literals for regex `r'\d+'` and this doesn't check if the numbers are part of a word also containing alpha characters (which seems to be the intent)

Comment: @Keozon Yes, raw string is better, I would change my answer. But what do you mean ''numbers are part of a word ", can you give an example?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I don't want to keep anything that has the following format in my string : '700/-', '+91 1234567891', '3appeared' , 'Vora02261794300Will'. Numbers or words such as the last two in the example should not be present in the string after processing.

Answer (score -1):

The code below checks each character for a digit.  If it isn't a digit, it adds the character to the end of the corrected string.

```
string = 'This string is not yet perfect1234 and 123pretty but it can be.'

CorrectedString = ""
for characters in string:
    if characters.isdigit():
        continue
    CorrectedString += characters
```

Comment: @PJay: No, it doesn't, it also removes digits alone.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this by simply join function and as well as nothing to import

```
str_var='This string 22 is not yet perfect1234 and 123pretty but it can be.'

str_var = ' '.join(x for x in str_var.split(' ') if x.isdigit() or x.isalpha())
print str_var
```

output:

```
'This string 22 is not yet perfect and pretty but it can be.'
```

Comment: @PJay: No, it doesn't work, it also removes digits alone.

Answer (score -1):

`print(''.join(x for x in strng if not x.isdigit()).replace('  ',' '))`

*p.s. after removing digits..replace double space(s) with single space(s)*

output:

`This string is not yet perfect and pretty but it can be.`