# Remove unmixed numbers from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Say I have a file called input.txt that looks like this

```
I listened to 4 u2 albums today
meet me at 5
squad 4ever
```

I want to filter out the numbers that are on their own, so "4" and "5" should go but "u2" and "4ever" should remain the same. i.e the output should be

```
I listened to u2 albums today
meet me at
squad 4ever
```

I've been trying to use this code

```
for line in fileinput.input("input.txt", inplace=True):
    new_s = ""
    for word in line.split(' '):
        if not all(char.isdigit() for char in word):
            new_s += word
            new_s += ' '
    print(new_s, end='')
```

Which is pretty similar to the code I found here: [Removing numbers mixed with letters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699616/removing-numbers-mixed-with-letters-from-string)

But instead of the wanted output I get

```
I listened to u2 albums today
 meet me at 5
 squad 4ever
```

As you can see there are two problems here, first only the first line loses the digit I want it to lose, "5" is still present in the second line. The second problem is the extra white space at the beginning of a new line.

I've been playing around with the code for a while and browsing stackoverflow, but can't find where the problem is coming from. Any insights?

Comment: The problem is that the last word on the line ends with `\n`. This is not a digit, so it passes the if statement, and the extra space is because you add a space each time in the for loop, including for the last word on the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.split(' ')` does not remove the trailing newlines from each line. They end up attached to the last word of the line. So for your first problem, the `'5'` doesn't get removed because it's actually `'5\n'`, and the `\n` is not a digit.

The second problem is related. When you print the last word of each line, it contains that newline, plus you're adding a space on to the end. That space shows up as the first character of the next line.

The simplest solution is simply to change `line.split(' ')` to `line.split()`. Without any arguments, `split()` will remove all whitespace, including the newlines. You'll also need to remove the `end=''` from your `print` so that the newlines are added back in.

Comment: There's also an extra space added at the end of each line (before the new line) that should be dealt with, possibly by using `print(new_s[:-1])`

Comment: @yinnonsanders Or by storing the words for each line in a list and doing a `' '.join()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use regexp.

```
re.sub(r"\b\d+\b", "", input)
```

match any digit between word boundaries

Or to avoid double spaces:

```
re.sub(r"\s\d+\s", " ", input)
```

Comment: That kind of works, but it leaves a white space instead of nothing when replacing a number, which turns "I listened to 4 u2 albums today" into "I listened to  u2 albums today", with 2 spaces between "to" and "u2".
Any way to fix this?

Comment: Edited with a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
data = open('file.txt').read()
import re
data = re.sub('(?<=\s)\d+(?=$)|(?<=^)\d+(?<=\s)|(\s\d+\s)', '', data)
```

Output:

```
I listened tou2 albums today
meet me at
squad 4ever
```